# Blacklisting sites in Firefox and IE to speed page load times

Tags: browser, internet-filter

I live in a country that strives hard to "harmonize" the Internet.

As such, a variety of sites are inaccessible because they lack "harmony."

To be honest, I can live quite happily without Facebook or Google+, **but** when other sites try to pull content therefrom upon loading, I have to sit and wait for the requests to time out (I can see this happening in my browser status bar) before their pages will fully load.

Is there something similar to NoScript but for full domains? In other words, I want my browser to automatically ignore all content requests to any domain in a list that I generate.

(Note that this is a little different from your standard web filter. I want to automatically and immediately ignore/deny all attempts by `siteIWantToVisit.com` to load content from `blockedSite.com`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like [BlockSite](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/blocksite/) suit your needs?

Comment: This looks promising. I'm going to try it and will report back.

Comment: Popping back in to say this works great. A good example is Wired.com -- it used to take forever to load because of Facebook hooks, but now is zippy as hell. Thanks OldWolf!

Comment: @Andrew Heath: Awesome, glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your hosts file.  You didnt mention your OS, but with a little googling, you can find the appropriate one.  Basically you can tell your PC that Facebook.com is somewhere other than it actually is.  Enter facebook.com into the hosts file and give it an address of 127.0.0.1 (local loopback) and you should be good to go, all requests to Facebook wont leave your PC.

Follow the directions [here](http://www.fpweb.net/support/managed-hosting/hostfile-editing-support.asp) on how to do if for Windows.

Comment: seems a little heavy-handed. If I wanted to use my VPN then I'd be blocking myself, correct? I'm looking for something I can toggle for those times when a VPN is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeedy. It's called (drumroll please) [YesScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yesscript/).

For something more automated, you'll want [Ghostery](http://www.ghostery.com/).

Comment: YesScript is not what I want. The problem isn't JS, it's the entire domain. Requesting *anything* from Facebook.com makes my browsers hang while they wait for the request to time-out. NoScript takes care of the JS, but I want to block **everything**. The hosts suggestion up above would work, but that'd be always on whereas I'd like a toggle...

Comment: @Andrew I think then, you may want to write an [Ablock Plus filter](https://adblockplus.org/en/filters).

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is the country you liv in, why not use a proxy server/s like TOR or proXPN to change the location you're browsing from, and bypass the problem all together? This also provides a single-button solution.

Comment: All bypass methods suffer speed problems, so we only use VPNs and the like when we want to access websites that are blocked.